# catalog_category_view.xml is there possibility to add custom xml file into product_list?

Tags: magento2, category-products

I'm trying to add custom label into each product in category view page but it doesn't work.

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Sticker" name="productlabel.sticker" template="Vendor_ModuleName::product/label.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="productlabel.sticker" destination="product_list" />
</body>
</page>
```

label.phtml

```
<img src="..." />
```

I know that i can override                 `<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">` and put this image in custom list.phtml, but i use this `productlabel.sticker`also in catalog_product_view.xml(works)

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="product.info.main" >
        <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Sticker"
               name="productlabel.sticker"
               template="Vendor_ModuleName::product/label.phtml"
               before="page.main.title"/>
    </referenceContainer>
    <move element="productlabel.sticker" destination="product.info.main" before="page.main.title" />
</body>
```

therefore i want insert it as xml block in catalog_category_view. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please write more about your query. post image example, it'll be good :)